# How to extend Backbone Model and keep defaults while using Coffeescript

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript, default-value

Given I have the following inheritance in coffeescript.

I get an error because "mammal" seems to be undefined for myCat.

I read in some other post that I would actually have to make defaults a function to inherit the default values. But how do I do this with coffeescript?

```
class Animal extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    mammal: true

class Cat extends Animal
  defaults:
    furColor: "gray"

myCat = new Cat
alert(myCat.get('mammal'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use functions for both `defaults`, then your `Cat` can simply call `super` and add a few things:

```
class Animal extends Backbone.Model
  defaults: ->
    mammal: true

class Cat extends Animal
  defaults: ->
    _(super()).extend(furColor: "gray")
```

You could keep the non-function `defaults` in `Animal` but that would get ugly so don't bother.

Note that [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) alters its first argument so usually you want to say things like `_({}).extend(...)` to avoid scribbling on things that you don't own. In this case, you know that `Animal#defaults` returns a brand new object every time it is called so you don't have to worry about that. If you're paranoid, you could do this instead:

```
defaults: ->
  _({}).extend(super(), furColor: 'gray')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LETAc/

Comment: This is what worked for me in the subclass: `defaults: -> _.extend super(), furColor: 'gray' `

Comment: @StuBlair: `_.f(x)` and `_(x).f()` are equivalent, I tend to use the latter because it reads better to me.